gcc make error on windows, how to resolve?
I'm trying to compile squid, a proxy and cache server, on windows using MinGW32 and MSYS32 for use with IIS and the make check and make install process is failing with these messages:
In file included from ../compat/compat.h:76,
                 from ../include/squid.h:66,
                 from assert.cc:32:
../compat/os/mswindows.h:178: error: "S_IRWXO" redefined [-Werror]
 #define S_IRWXO 007

In file included from ../compat/os/mswindows.h:54,
                 from ../compat/compat.h:76,
                 from ../include/squid.h:66,
                 from assert.cc:32:
C:/Strawberry/c/i686-w64-mingw32/include/sys/stat.h:163: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define S_IRWXO    (S_IRWXG >> 3)

cc1plus.exe: all warnings being treated as errors
make[1]: *** [Makefile:907: assert.lo] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/msys32/home/paulg/squid-3.4.14/compat'
make: *** [Makefile:572: check-recursive] Error 1


I think its the -Werror flag causing these errors but I could be wrong. All the components are in the location recommended on the squid for windows website and the paths are correct. If anyone has ever done this successfully please let me know.
deleted the flag -Werror from the makefile, the error still shows.

You need to make your problem reproducible by showing
all commands you executed to get to it.

squid just isn't ready yet for Windows if you ask me. I tried building it, but there is so many stuff in the code that doesn't work on Windows. If you want to see how I overcame some of the build obstacles you can check my build recipe here: https://github.com/brechtsanders/winlibs_recipes/blob/main/recipes_work_in_progress/squid.winlib
